# How to convert this download code to CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm new to using codedom.

Can someone tell me how to convert this code to be run in C#?

Code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: What conversion do you need? This is already C# code that will work just fine. Could you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does your text file have code in it that you want to inject using codedom?

Comment: No I mean put it into a way for codedom is compile.. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1):

A fully working CodeDom code sample is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx

Copy the code for `CodeDomExample` into a new class file (*.cs) and modify the `CodeTypeReferenceExpression`  and the subsequent `CodeMethodInvokeExpression` instances to what you need.